# Is it possible & safe to use latest kernel with Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, linux-kernel, upgrade

I have been using Debian stable which currently uses version 5.10 of the Linux kernel. However now I want to try out 6.0.9. Is it possible to manually install a new Linux kernel instead of the one my distribution ships with? Is there a possibility that things will break?

Comment: Everything is possible. However… If you get out-of-tree drivers you should first ensure that they are compatible with the new kernel version. (e.g. I would not venture on this if running whatever legacy nvidia proprietary driver)

Comment: Go ahead. Unlikely.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to manually install a new Linux kernel instead of the one my distribution ships with?

Yes, You are on Debian Bullseye, the easy way is to install a new kernel from  Bullseye-Backports. Here is how to install it:

Adding Backports see [instructions](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/):

```
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main" |
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian-backports.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -t bullseye-backports linux-image-amd64
sudo reboot
```

It is safe to install a new kernel from Debian Backports.

> [About Backports](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/#index1h2)

> Debian Backports are considered generally safe when used as intended on an individual package basis.

[Debian Wiki: Backports](https://wiki.debian.org/Backports)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Just configure it with all the needed drivers and it will work.

Since it is very important program, of course things could go wrong, especially first time. But you will have the original distribution kernel by side, and hopefully you won't get your bootloader screwed enough, so that could be fixed in a single reboot  and manual choice of Debian's shipped kernel.

See, for example, [here](https://www.krenger.ch/blog/debian-with-a-vanilla-kernel/).

Another question could arise: does it have a new feature that you desire to have? If you won't use it, there is no point of using newer kernel, because old features will likely work the same way, so you won't see any difference. And, since Debian's is patched against known vulnerabilities, it is no less secure than latest kernel.org version, just has less features.

Answer (score 1):

At first: The other answers surely are correct, but maybe not totally complete. From [this debian document](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToUpgradeKernel) (emphasis mine):

> There are some alternative repositories for images, but they aren't
> supported, **and don't receive security updates** (in a timely fashion):
>
> - for DebianStable, use StableProposedUpdates or **Backports;**
> - for DebianUnstable and DebianExperimental, use something like:
>   [ ...]

This means that backported kernels are usually easy to install and safe in the sense that they won't break things, **but they may be insecure** because they don't receive timely security updates. I would recommend thinking twice before using them on a production system, especially in public internet.